MULTI RING BUFFER VECTOR LAYER TO RASTER
I have a line vector file in qgis in which I run the multi-ring buffer command to divide the area into 200m zones from the river because I want to make a flood hazard map.

So I have a multi ring buffer vector layer that I want to rasterize without losing any data in the transfer.I go to Raster -> conversion ->rasterize (vector to raster) but something is always going wrong
I need this raster layer to add to the final equation in the raster calculator to do multicriteria flood risk analysis.

So... you run rasterize? Or what is your question?

yes i go to Raster -> conversion ->rasterize (vector to raster) but something is always going wrong

maybe i am selecting something wrong. but i have tried it with 1010 , 5050, 90*90 pixels or georeferenced units

Please do not use ALL CAPS in your question titles.

Use the documentation.
You need to set:

Output raster size units
Width/horizontal resolution
Height/vertical resolution

and you probably want to select a field to use for a burn in value, I use the distance field of my buffered layer:

